# Django DRF create foreign key field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to create simple serialiser which should from `{'campaign_id': 1}` return in `validated_field` field `campaign` with the company model. For active this target, I created

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    campaign_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Campaign.objects.all())
```

and got in campaign_id needed campaign, but when I tried to rename campaign_id to campaign and use the `source`, I got an error. How to do this?

Code for reproduce

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    campaign = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Campaign.objects.all(), source='campaign_id')

validator = CampaignSerializer(data={'campaign_id': 1})
validator.is_valid(True)
```

Exception: `ValidationError: {'campaign': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}`

Comment: show the error please

Comment: This error in the test. ```AssertionError: 400 != 200 : {'campaign': ['This field is required.']}``` My new string is ```campaign = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Campaign.objects.all(), source='campaign_id')```

Comment: Ok, how you get that error? Is it a some api call manually or in the test? Give more context